# Is there a limit on how much reputation one can earn in 24 hours?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, reputation

My account seems to be capped at 305 for today despite additional up votes.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I found the answer in the FAQ (had to hit the expand button , thought I saw that before).

Can we consider increasing the daily limit of extra good helpers =)

Comment: That likely won't happen, the 200 rep limit is just as much a good thing as it may seem a bad. If you're hitting 200 rep daily, you should probably take a break from the internet. Maybe open a window, take a walk, get some sleep, etc :)

Comment: I understand, it was a lame attempt at humor after fumbling through the FAQ.