# Increasing reputation cap in accordance with trust

Tags: feature-request, reputation

In response to a small three-person [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/rep-cap-discussion) on Chat, I am requesting that the rep cap be increased as the user gains more trust. This could be done as `200+(rep/10)` as more trusted users have less of a chance to "spam" with many one-upvote insignificant answers.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap

Comment: Can you be a chap and do that for me? Short time, big night.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## No.

Let's not do this.

<sub>---Add reasoning and ideas below this line---</sub>

I think keeping it the same could contribute to higher rep users letting lower rep users approach the threshold instead of banging out all the answers.

Some users are more than capable of answering far more questions than they do.

We definitely need more users with higher privilege levels instead of a couple users with insanely high reputation.

This helps users return to the site for rep since they may only earn 200 at a time, so they can't just get 1000 votes quickly, become a trusted user, then with a sense of fulfillment, leave the site.

---

"That likely won't happen, the 200 rep limit is just as much a good thing as it may seem a bad. If you're hitting 200 rep daily, you should probably take a break from the internet. Maybe open a window, take a walk, get some sleep, etc :)" <sub>[marco ceppi](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2209/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-reputation-one-can-earn-in-24-hours)</sub> - good advice!